# Unable to render svg properly with the flutter_svg package

Tags: flutter, svg, flutter-dependencies

Svg is not rendering properly with flutter_svg package. Always gives an error like :-

```
Failed to find definition for url(#pattern0)
```

Have tried moving up the `<defs>` at the top but still no luck. Don't know if doing something wrong as i have little experience with svg's.

Here is the svg file i am trying to render

[Svg File](https://gist.github.com/bharat8/19ba7975dcd6c5614d48fee7fb3b8d6b?short_path=cd86a1c)

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Place   tag path

```
<svg width="272" height="153" viewBox="0 0 272 153" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_1_14700" x1="136" y1="0" x2="136" y2="153" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#028FF0"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0DC1D9"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<path d="M227.5 109.5L0 153H272V0L227.5 109.5Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_1_14700)" fill-opacity="0.03"/>
```

Comment: Forgive me but i don't undertand how path tag is going to help. I have a rectangle and inside that, i used fill property. Have you tried to render the svg i attached?

Comment: please add your svg code

Comment: I have already attached a hyperlink for the code.